# cannot access django development server running on Linode from outside

Tags: linode

I just setup a django development server on a Linode and wanted to access it from outside. The server is running on port 8000. But the linode is not allowing me to access this port from outside.

I checked that iptables didn't have any rule set to block the traffic.

Is there some specific place where I need to configure the list of ports on which HTTP traffic is allowed from outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Django dev server binds to 127.0.0.1. Bind it to 0.0.0.0 instead. But keep in mind that the dev server is a pile of bleep that's not for production use.

Comment: +1 - You can bind to 0.0.0.0 or to a single IP if you have many interfaces. You can also change the port number if you need to with `manage.py runserver IP:port_number`

Comment: Thanx a lot.. It was my silly mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

too add to what ignacio said.. the full command is

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: yes. This command perfectly works.